# nose.run returns blank file when used with xunit arguments

Tags: python-unittest, nose

I am using nose to run my tests the following way

```
import nose
import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases = unittest.TestLoader().discover(<path_to_test_files>)
    suite = unittest.TestSuite([test_cases])
    xunit_report = True
    log_file = 'my_report.xml'
    arguments = ["nosetest",'--verbosity=2']
    if xunit_report:
        arguments += ['--with-xunit', '--xunit-file', log_file]
    nose.run(suite=suite, argv=arguments)
```

The suite variable is updated with all the test cases discovered. The console log also validates that all the tests got executed.
However, the xml result file always contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testsuite name="nosetests" tests="0" errors="0" failures="0" skip="0"></testsuite>
```

Am on Python 2.7.14.

What do I need to change to get the actual results in my xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `discover()` call to a provide a path, like `.` for the current directory:

```
test_cases = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
```

Then the loader will find files in the working directory that you are executing the script from that match the pattern `'test*.py'`. If I add add your script to a file `run.py`, and a test next to it in a file named `test_example.py`, with the following UnitTest test:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')
```

Then the output xml file contains the expected test results.

So: Make sure you're running the script from the same directory your tests are in (or that you change `.discover('.')` to whatever directory your tests are in, and that your test files match the `test*.py` pattern.

Also note that that `nose.run(..)` has an argument for just a module name to find tests in that you may find useful:

```
nose.run(module=".")
```

Comment: Thanks jakewins. I should have been more clear. I can see the test cases in the suite variable. I have provided the to discover .I can also see the tests being executed in the console output.

I just pass the suite object to the run method and the options. Yet the log is not populated.